# Please tell people not to use Hi / Thanks on the Ask Question page

Tags: feature-request, design, asking-questions

Please can this section mention no Hi / Thanks taglines?

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Something like this:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Almost every single new question has to have "Thanks in advance" edited out.

Comment: Won't help one bit, unfortunately.

Comment: @Won't it may do something... currently they have to click a link etc to find the rules.

Comment: Unfortunately that information is situated in the sidebar, where people are conditioned to ignore.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Hmm maybe some new users read it? Am I a little optimistic?